# Error Calling Method On NPObject: (A desicive One) PhoneGap Project

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

How Can I Call An Android Activity from JavaScript Function . I found A way , But When I try

It shows  Error:: Method  Called On NPObject. Can Any One solve It? It IS Killing Me.

Efforts Will Be Highly Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

just post your code of Interaction with UI in runOnUiThread

this link may help you

[Sometimes throws Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758397/sometimes-throws-uncaught-error-error-calling-method-on-npobject-on-android)

Comment: Thanks Mitul, I tried it To run In runONUiThread , But It Could Not Get The Intent() Of New Activity tO be Passed.Can U Give AN Example To DO That

Comment: i can't get you. can you say where you want to pass intent() of new Activity ?

Comment: Hello Rohit, you got our answer ?

Comment: Thank U Mitul I worked Out With Your suggestion. Thanks Again